# Hydro-Enforced/surface constraint DEM Creation using GRASS/QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, open-source-gis, dem, terrain

I am wondering if there is a way to create a hydro-breakline enforced DEM by means of any open source solution?

I am able to create a DEM from Lidar data using GRASS, but would like to enforce some 3D hydro breaklines into the DEM.  I am looking for something similar to creating a DEM from a Terrain available from ESRI.

Any ideas?

-Jeremy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GRASS GIS, you can use [r.carve](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.carve.html), hence take vector stream data, transform to raster data model and subtract the depth from the DEM using this module. See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Hydrological_Sciences